# Using NUI with a CollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, nui

I'm using the NUI library for customizing appearance of my iOS app. I had set my project up to use a UICollectionView, but I cannot seem to get the background of my UICollectionViewCells to set correctly.  Does anyone have an example of using NUI with a UICollectionView? (and I do realize there is not a NUI category for UICollectionView yet, but I'm hoping for a workaround.)